# bash: npm: command not found in Debian 9.3

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, debian-stretch

I am using Debian 9.3. (stretch) I cannot run "npm" commands.

Output for `node -v`

```
bash: node: command not found
```

Output for `nodejs -v`

```
v4.8.2
```

Output for `npm -v`

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

I'm a newbie on Debian and I can't understand what's happening.
- I already reinstall Node.js
- I already tried following the steps of the [Official Page](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm?utm_source=house&utm_medium=homepage&utm_campaign=free%20orgs&utm_term=Install%20npm).
- I already ran `apt-get install npm` Output `E: Unable to locate package npm`.
- I was at Debian Testing and have the same error when I was there.

Thanks for read and help
- Melt

Comment: Visit this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04 Hope that helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to locate package npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371904/e-unable-to-locate-package-npm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you installed node js from their website? if that's not the case remove it `apt-get remove nodejs`
and install it from this link (follow this steps)
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

---

### EDIT

After seing your version i realized that you are running an older version of nodejs... please remove the current nodejs version (V4.8.2) and install it via this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions
It will give you the last version (mine is V9.2.0) with NPM installed aswell.

Comment: Yes I did it from their website initially. :B

Comment: @OrlandoCartagena can you give the output of `which npm` ?

Comment: Also realized now that your nodejs is not up to date ... you are running v4 while the last version is v9.2 ... it might be that

Comment: I reinstall it and still 4.8.2 version.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I'm stupid .. I was typing " curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -" and on debian is " curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash - " ... after the sudo comand. Thaks a lot ! :B

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem with debian then I tried this and problem solved.

Run this is command

> curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

check version

> npm -v

You should see this after doing these steps
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You got an old version of the package (append to me on debian 9)

if you try : `apt-cache show  nodejs` i think you will see the multiple version proposal.

just find the good repository name you want to use for your nodejs install :

Exemple for me it was :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x stretch main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x stretch main
```

And force the use of stretch repository during install :

```
sudo apt install -t stretch nodejs
```

since install is complete you got all the packages in the expected versions :

```
$ nodejs -v
v10.7.0
$ npm -v
6.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If `nodejs -v` shows version, it means nodejs is installed. you need to create soft link for node. Run below commands:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

And run

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

Now check `node -v` and `npm -v`. It will show version.

Comment: 'Node -v' Works know, but 'npm -v' ins't working yet. :B

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install npm`

Comment: 'E: Unable to locate package npm'  :B

Comment: RESOLVED .. Thanks for help me ! :B